# Classification of finite groups with exponent $3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with exponenet $3$. I know that
$G$ does not have to be abelian. As an exmaple, the group of upper triangular $3\times3$ matrices over $F_p$ with $1$'s on the main diagonal ("finite Heisenberg group") have exponent $3$, but is not abelian.

**My question**: Is there a known classification of such groups?

Comment: No, there is no such classification. For references see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112357/groups-of-exponent-4) (which comes up easily when you try to search). Finite groups of exponent $3$ must be nilpotent of class $c\le 3$ and $2$-Engel groups.

Comment: Thanks @Dietrich Burde.

Comment: You are welcome (I didn't downvote)

Comment: Note also that the Burnside group $B(3,r)$, which is the largest $r$-generated group with exponent $3$ has order $3^{m(r)}$, where $m(r) = r + \binom{r}{2} + \binom{r}{3}$. There is a proof in Marshall Hall's book "TheTheory of Groups".